# Disable bulk updating on a Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

Is there a way that I can disable a trigger during bulk-lead-updates? Can I have it only take effect during a single record update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add code like this:

```
trigger calcSum5 on Lead (before insert, before update) 
{
    if (Trigger.new.size() > 1) return;
    ...
}
```

at the start of your trigger so the rest of the trigger code does not run for the bulk case. However you may regret doing that in the future if it leaves your data model in an unexpected condition for the bulk case.

Comment: Well that might work! In what circumstances do you think this could slip through the cracks and cause an unexpected condition?

Comment: @AlexBrigham The risk is up to you to assess. Triggers that work in both the single record and bulk case ensure that the data model gets put into the same state whether an update is done through the UI or through some (bulk) API. But that might not matter for you.

Comment: Great, thank you for your answer. I will try it out and let you know how it works!

Comment: Hey Keith, this works perfectly. Thank you SO much!

Alex